# Why isn't SetWindowRgn working as it should?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing a win32 app on windows 11.

Now am creating a static control and then setting a rounded `HRGN` by calling `SetWindowRgn`, But when I call `GetWindowRgn` After calling it, I receive a code `ERROR`.

In the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrgn#return-value) it says that we will only receive that code if the window doesn't have a region or if there was an error retrieving the region.

Here is some of the code:

```
HWND text = CreateWindow(
                TEXT("STATIC"), 
                L"Hello", 
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
                100, 100, 100, 50, 
                hWnd /* Parent Window */, 
                HMENU(NULL), 
                GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
                NULL
            );

HRGN textRgn = CreateRoundRectRgn(100, 100, 200, 150, 10, 10); 
   // Sorry wrong function. But it still doesn't seem to display the rounded corners (before it was CreateRectRgn)

SetWindowRgn(text, textRgn, TRUE);

std::cout << GetWindowRgn(text, textRgn) << std::endl; // Logging 0 (i.e. ERROR)
```

Again, I'm not sure if there is a problem in my code, but I did receive some information from other [sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/825465/on-windows-11-getwindowrgn-doesn39t-seem-to-return.html) about something about it being a problem exclusive to windows 10 and 11.

I could be wrong about it being a windows problem. But either way I just want to know where the problem is.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the documentation notes, SetWindowRgn takes ownership of the region. You can't use it as the output of another function. It's not yours any more.

Comment: Ok, I just want to change the shape of the static control. But that is not happening either.

Comment: Linked to dup, and use CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, 100, 50, 10, 10)

Comment: @HansPassant I still do not know what to do. Could you post an answer?

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, thank you so much. Calling `CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, 100, 50, 10, 10)`  worked fine.